# Setting owner of a file in java ( ver-7) in Windows XP SP2

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalLookupService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SetOwnerOfFile{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Path path=Paths.get("c:\\demotext.txt");
        try{
            UserPrincipal owner=Files.getOwner(path);
            System.out.format("The owner of file is: %s%n",owner.getName());

            UserPrincipalLookupService lookupservice=FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
            Files.setOwner(path,lookupservice.lookupPrincipalByName("joe"));

            UserPrincipal newowner=Files.getOwner(path);
            System.out.format("Now the owner of file is: %s%n",newowner.getName());
        }
        catch(UnsupportedOperationException x){
            System.err.println(x);
        }
        catch(IOException x){
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

The owner of file is: \Everyone

java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException

The program is throwing IOException. Does it mean my OS restricts modification of the owner of a file? If not, please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I validate your code. **The issue is not in updating the `owner` but finding the `UserPrincinpal`.** If you breakup statements below:

```
        UserPrincipalLookupService lookupservice=FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
        Files.setOwner(path,lookupservice.lookupPrincipalByName("joe"));
```

as this:

```
        UserPrincipalLookupService lookupservice=FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = lookupservice.lookupPrincipalByName("joe");
        Files.setOwner(path,userPrincipal);
```

You will get the issue at second line. It may be the case that **it's not able to find an existing "Windows User" with name as "joe"**.

I tried this with my windows user, and was successful in changing the owner.

Comment: Thanks @Yogendra. I tried what you said. It's still throwing the same exception. The program can't find User Principal. Do you know what it means? Btw I am using an administrator account with the name "lonovo".

Comment: But now the line number should be pointing to `lookupservice.lookupPrincipalByName("joe");` line. Try setting the owner as "lonovo". It should go through.

Comment: Yeah! It works but problem still exists.    **Output:**  The owner of file is: \Everyone    Now the owner of file is: \Everyone    I think my OS wont allow me to change the owner of file.

Comment: You are using the admin account to create and update the file. Try identifying another existing user account on the system and assign that one. :)

Comment: I turned the **Guest** account on. Updated and compiled the file. But still the owner is: \Everyone

Comment: Try this. Create a file using "guest", make sure, owner is printed as "guest", then set owner as "lonovo" and see the output. This worked for me as it is. please Note: Its looking for the accounts in your system. If still doesn't work, please share your debugger output for critical steps/objects.